# Can I push 1 file from a branch to the master without merging full branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, git-merge

I have 2 branches & here was my thoughts: I would do all the work on the branch--beta and then when OK with that I would push that particular file up to the master - essentially populating the master branch file by file. I cannot seem to do this without merging the 2 branches into 1 which I don't want to do until much later.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You could commit and push one file at a time (from local branch to remote branch) and then merge from branch to master after each push

Comment: *Only* commits, _implying all their ancestors_, can be merged. Commits can also be rebased (“moved”) or cherry-picked (“duplicated”) without being merged. The trees will still be divergent, even if the content is identical, until actually merged. Commits contain whatever they contain.

Comment: Cherry-picking a commit, for example, is _unlike_ a merge in that it results in a new commit at the target ancestry location.

Comment: You cannot push "a file", as `git push` sends only entire commits. In general, you will want to make one or more new commits that add on just after some existing commit, and then use `git push` to send the new commits. There's no requirement that the new commits be merge commits, but they must be new commits that add on to the last commit in the chain of commits stored in the *other Git repository* (i.e., add on to *their* branch).

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific files to a commit, push and merge it with master.

For adding just one file to a commit-

```
git add {filepath}
git commit -m {"Your message"}
git push
```

For merging it with master-

```
git checkout master
git merge beta
git push
```